# C# List Split and Join Specific Length

Tags: c#, sql

I pull object in MSSQL and i would like to try below

List for example

> Num1 = 123123
>
> Num2 = 2222
>
> Num3 = 3456734567
>
> Num4 = 4669321469321

How do i combine this list since the length is not the same?

Expected Result :

> CombinedNum = 123223456746693211232234567469321

Code i tryed :

```
 List<string> first4List = new List<string>();
                List<string> Num_1List = new List<string>();
                List<string> Num_2List = new List<string>();
                List<string> Num_3List = new List<string>();
                List<string> Num_4List = new List<string>();

              while (render.Read())
                {
               first4List.Add(render["N1"].ToString());
               last4List.Add(render["N2"].ToString());
               HashList.Add(render["N3"].ToString());
               FlagList.Add(render["N4"].ToString());
               ReasonList.Add(render["N5"].ToString());
                render.Close();
```

Comment: it seems only you know what you want. read the help ,QA documents how to put a question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: are you trying to combine numbers sequentially or is there any order? please edit your question to make it more meaningful. thanks

Comment: i try to put it in order

Comment: I didn't get how you have come up with your Expected Result.

Comment: CombinedNum = {num1}{num2}{num3}{num4}

Comment: but take those num 1 ~ 4 on spesific length

Comment: your requested CombinedNum = {num1}{num2}{num3}{num4} does not equal your stated expectations of CombinedNum = 123223456746693211232234567469321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to achieve is to generate a string that is a combination of all elements in a list then try the below.

```
   var Num_1List = new List<string>
            {
                "123123", "2222", "3456734567", "4669321469321"
            };

            var combinedString = Num_1List.Aggregate((current, part) => current + part);
```